# How to get a date from p:clock?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to save a date from a p:clock tag into a java.util.Date object and how to move the p:clock to the right in my xhtml page, ¿How can I do that?.

I'm new at Jsf.

I'm using jsf/primefaces/ManagedBeans and Jpa (to save those objects). If you need something else like my managedbeans feel free to tell me. I'll update this thread as soon as possible.

Thanks your for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping inputText to Date object in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10699680/mapping-inputtext-to-date-object-in-jsf)

Comment: p:clock is an output component, not an input one. It displays either the client side time which you can access easily from javascript, or the server time which you have easy access to on the server. So this is a kind of weird requirement.